# Sound or light reversible super glue possible?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Sorry if this is a stupid question and help me to improve it.

Super glue is meant to be quick and mostly universal but we can stick to ceramics and/ or wood.

Imagine you put parts with the glue together.

Then later on a specific light or sound frequency would weaken the glue bonds.

Total nonsense, reality or research topic?

Comment: Could be done with light - a *lot* of UV could degrade the cyanoacrylate, but would be impractical (takes too long, releases toxic fumes, needs access to the glued layer so at least one object must be UV-transparent).

Comment: USC has a [temperature reversible super glue](https://eye.keckmedicine.org/?post_type=post_press_release&p=15533) for treating battlefield eye injuries.